# Word for "starting a horse"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that means "to start a horse" or "make a horse start moving"? Something like "he [started] his horse".

I thought of "urged her horse on" but that sounds like the horse is already moving. "Brought his horse to a canter" sounds okay but I want something that doesn't specify the speed, just shows that the horse has started moving.

I feel like there's a single word that means what I'm trying to say, but I can't find it.

Comment: **Click** the horse into moving? (The sound made by your tongue against one cheek).

Comment: There's always "spurred".

Comment: You might use "prodded" or "spurred" depending on whether the person that is starting the horse is saddled on it or not.

Comment: @user22542 - Even if saddled, "prodded" may be appropriate.  One can kind of knee the horse to encourage it to move.  But it depends on the horse.  For some you only need to loosen the reins, with others you shake the reins, and stubborn ones will need a spur or whip.

Comment: True. Can "gee up" be used as a verb? It might work in the right sentence.

Comment: @user22542 - "Gee" and "haw" are terms for "turn right" and "turn left".  What you've heard is no doubt "giddy up" or one of its variants.  (Etymonline does list "gee-up" as an alternative to "giddy-up", but it's even rarer than the other terms here.)

Comment: OK. Actually, you can find "gee-up" in several places if you look.  It's an exclamation, I guess. It can also mean start up/go forward as a command to a horse. Lots of different spellings too, but it is slang and informal. Free your mind - I was just asking about a possibility.  Couple of links - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gee-up.  and https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/gee-up

Comment: I actually thought "start a horse" was funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on **how** you start the horse. If you use the metal, spiky device worn just beneath your heel, you can try **[spur](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spur)**, as suggested by Hot Licks in a comment; this verb is used traditionally and widely across the world. Spur, as a verb means:

> **1.** Urge (a horse) forward by digging one's spurs into its sides.
>
> He **spurred** his horse.

Additionally, [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-24581,00.html) says:

> You make a horse move by shouting **"Giddyup!"**. You make a pack of dogs move by shouting "**Mush!**".

Hence, this is another way post the verb "spur."

---

Conversely, its antonym may be the phrase **[hold your horses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hold_your_horses)** used chiefly in horse driving meaning to "stay on" or "wait a minute".